# Add custom image upload attribute to product

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, product-attribute, upgrade, upgrade-script

I Have tried to add new image upload attribute to Magento Product using sql upgrade script, but I got the error message like:

> Invalid backend model specified:
>   catalog/product_attribute_backend_image

The file has name `upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` which is correct because I see new version in `core_resource` table.

There is my code:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'image_cert', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'group' => 'Design',
    'label' => 'Certificate Image',
    'input' => 'image',
    'backend' => 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_image',
    'required' => false,
    'sort_order' => 55,
    'global' => 1
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code (base image attribute)

```
<?php
$setup = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');

$attr = array (
  'attribute_model' => NULL,
  'backend' => NULL,
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'table' => NULL,
  'frontend' => 'catalog/product_attribute_frontend_image',
  'input' => 'media_image',
  'label' => 'Base Image',
  'frontend_class' => NULL,
  'source' => NULL,
  'required' => '0',
  'user_defined' => '0',
  'default' => NULL,
  'unique' => '0',
  'note' => NULL,
  'input_renderer' => NULL,
  'global' => '0',
  'visible' => '1',
  'searchable' => '0',
  'filterable' => '0',
  'comparable' => '0',
  'visible_on_front' => '0',
  'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '0',
  'is_used_for_price_rules' => '0',
  'filterable_in_search' => '0',
  'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
  'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
  'is_configurable' => '1',
  'apply_to' => NULL,
  'visible_in_advanced_search' => '0',
  'position' => '0',
  'wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
  'used_for_promo_rules' => '0',
  'tooltip' => NULL,
  'max_len' => '0',
  'option' => 
  array (
    'values' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
);
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'image', $attr);

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'image');
$attribute->setStoreLabels(array (
));
$attribute->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create attribute from backend itself:

1. *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Create New Attribute*
2. Select *Catalog Input Type for Store Owner* as **Media Image**
3. Put this attribute in Image Group of your attribute set.
4. Do Index Management
5. Clear caches

Comment: thanks, but this way is not right. I explain you. For example I have live / stage / dev / local versions of my site. In this case I have to repeat your solution 4 site * 5 steps = 20 iterations. But I can do it by upgrade-x.x.x-x.x.y and it will be more correct